# Fluent Assertions check if all endpoints have a specific swagger attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, xunit, fluent-assertions

I want to check if all endpoints of my ASP.NET Core API controllers have an attribute that looks line this:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,typeof(*different types*))]
```

I used xUnit and Fluent Assertions to write this:

```
[Fact]
public void EndpointsSwaggerAttribute()
{
      typeof(BaseController).Methods().Should().BeDecoratedWith<SwaggerResponseAttribute>(s =>(s.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString()));
}
```

But it does not quite work. It always passes the test. Base controller is a helper class that inherits ControllerBase and all controllers inherit Base Controller.

Comment: You are only checking BaseController and not all Controllers _inheriting_ from BaseController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you want to check if all endpoints of API controllers have SwaggerResponse attribute,you need firstly get the assembly of your api project and then get all the methods in project:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //if the unit test exsit in the api project...
        //Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //if your unit test project seprate from the api project
        //you could get the api project assembly like below
        var asm = typeof(WeatherForecastController).Assembly;
        
        //get all the methods in project
        var methods = asm.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type)) 
        .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)).ToList();
                    
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {              
            //check if the method has SwaggerResponse attribute  
            var result = Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(SwaggerResponseAttribute));
            Assert.True(result, $"{method.Name} should be declared with SwaggerResponse Attribute");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, thanks. Could this solution be used to check if all methods have a SwaggerResponseAttribute with a specific status code?

Answer (score 1):

Does the `BaseController` have methods at all? If not, you'll need to first list the concrete types and use the `Methods` extension method on that.

However, I would actually write HTTP API tests (using the ASP.NET Core `HostBuilder`) that verify that the observable output of your Swagger endpoint is correct.

Comment: For suggestion to verify via actual HTTP API tests ;)

Comment: I totally agree to have a test running the web api in self host to get the swagger but how do you ensure you didn't miss an annotation?

Comment: You need that annotation to get the Swagger to return something in a certain way, right? If you know that, I would also expect an HTTP test that verifies that.

Comment: But the annotation has purely a documentation purpose. So you could have an HTTP call to check your endpoint is returning the expected type and you could also have an HTTP call to check the Swagger is correctly generated but that doesn't mean the notation/return type documentation has been applied to the endpoint and it's present into the Swagger. You can potentially parse the Swagger and really try every call to see if what you get correspond to the Swagger declared type but it seems a bit overkill where checking the annotations would be enough no?

Comment: It's a matter of choice. I prefer not to look at internal implementation details in a test.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're only looking the methods directly inside BaseController, you have to get all children class:

```
        var baseControllerType = typeof(BaseController);
        var controllerTypes = baseControllerType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t != type
                                                      && type.IsAssignableFrom(BaseController))
```

Then for each controller you can apply the same logic.

Comment: I don't get why you use `type`. Did you mean to use baseControllerType?

Comment: Yes sorry, I made a small sample locally and forgot to change the name :s